# Android Motion Detection | How not to paint red color on the captured images

Tags: java, android, image-processing, android-camera, rgb

I'm trying to make a motion detection app by comparing RGB values based on this (https://github.com/phishman3579/android-motion-detection) app. Everything is working fine, it does captures image when motion is detected. But it paints a red color on the captured images. 
I would like to get rid of the red color and make the image look normal.

This is how it looks now:
[image]

Is there any other better ways to do motion detection?

**RgbMotionDetection.java**

```
public class RgbMotionDetection implements IMotionDetection {

// private static final String TAG = "RgbMotionDetection";

// Specific settings
private static final int mPixelThreshold = 100; // Difference in pixel (RGB)
private static final int mThreshold = 10000; // Number of different pixels
                                             // (RGB)

private static int[] mPrevious = null;
private static int mPreviousWidth = 0;
private static int mPreviousHeight = 0;

/**
 * {@inheritDoc}
 */
@Override
public int[] getPrevious() {
    return ((mPrevious != null) ? mPrevious.clone() : null);
}

protected static boolean isDifferent(int[] first, int width, int height) {
    if (first == null) throw new NullPointerException();

    if (mPrevious == null) return false;
    if (first.length != mPrevious.length) return true;
    if (mPreviousWidth != width || mPreviousHeight != height) return true;

    int totDifferentPixels = 0;
    for (int i = 0, ij = 0; i < height; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++, ij++) {
            int pix = (0xff & (first[ij]));
            int otherPix = (0xff & (mPrevious[ij]));

            // Catch any pixels that are out of range
            if (pix < 0) pix = 0;
            if (pix > 255) pix = 255;
            if (otherPix < 0) otherPix = 0;
            if (otherPix > 255) otherPix = 255;

            if (Math.abs(pix - otherPix) >= mPixelThreshold) {
                totDifferentPixels++;
                // Paint different pixel red
                first[ij] = Color.RED;
            }
        }
    }
    if (totDifferentPixels <= 0) totDifferentPixels = 1;
    boolean different = totDifferentPixels > mThreshold;
    /*
     * int size = height * width; int percent =
     * 100/(size/totDifferentPixels); String output =
     * "Number of different pixels: " + totDifferentPixels + "> " + percent
     * + "%"; if (different) { Log.e(TAG, output); } else { Log.d(TAG,
     * output); }
     */
    return different;
}

/**
 * Detect motion comparing RGB pixel values. {@inheritDoc}
 */
@Override
public boolean detect(int[] rgb, int width, int height) {
    if (rgb == null) throw new NullPointerException();

    int[] original = rgb.clone();

    // Create the "mPrevious" picture, the one that will be used to check
    // the next frame against.
    if (mPrevious == null) {
        mPrevious = original;
        mPreviousWidth = width;
        mPreviousHeight = height;
        // Log.i(TAG, "Creating background image");
        return false;
    }

    // long bDetection = System.currentTimeMillis();
    boolean motionDetected = isDifferent(rgb, width, height);
    // long aDetection = System.currentTimeMillis();
    // Log.d(TAG, "Detection "+(aDetection-bDetection));

    // Replace the current image with the previous.
    mPrevious = original;
    mPreviousWidth = width;
    mPreviousHeight = height;

    return motionDetected;
}
}
```

**ImageProcessing.java**

```
public abstract class ImageProcessing {

public static final int A = 0;
public static final int R = 1;
public static final int G = 2;
public static final int B = 3;

public static final int H = 0;
public static final int S = 1;
public static final int L = 2;

private ImageProcessing() {
}

/**
 * Get RGB values from pixel.
 * 
 * @param pixel
 *            Integer representation of a pixel.
 * @return float array of a,r,g,b values.
 */
public static float[] getARGB(int pixel) {
    int a = (pixel >> 24) & 0xff;
    int r = (pixel >> 16) & 0xff;
    int g = (pixel >> 8) & 0xff;
    int b = (pixel) & 0xff;
    return (new float[] { a, r, g, b });
}

/**
 * Get HSL (Hue, Saturation, Luma) from RGB. Note1: H is 0-360 (degrees)
 * Note2: S and L are 0-100 (percent)
 * 
 * @param r
 *            Red value.
 * @param g
 *            Green value.
 * @param b
 *            Blue value.
 * @return Integer array representing an HSL pixel.
 */
public static int[] convertToHSL(int r, int g, int b) {
    float red = r / 255;
    float green = g / 255;
    float blue = b / 255;

    float minComponent = Math.min(red, Math.min(green, blue));
    float maxComponent = Math.max(red, Math.max(green, blue));
    float range = maxComponent - minComponent;
    float h = 0, s = 0, l = 0;

    l = (maxComponent + minComponent) / 2;

    if (range == 0) { // Monochrome image
        h = s = 0;
    } else {
        s = (l > 0.5) ? range / (2 - range) : range / (maxComponent +                                        minComponent);

        if (red == maxComponent) {
            h = (blue - green) / range;
        } else if (green == maxComponent) {
            h = 2 + (blue - red) / range;
        } else if (blue == maxComponent) {
            h = 4 + (red - green) / range;
        }
    }

    // convert to 0-360 (degrees)
    h *= 60;
    if (h < 0) h += 360;

    // convert to 0-100 (percent)
    s *= 100;
    l *= 100;

    // Since they were converted from float to int
    return (new int[] { (int) h, (int) s, (int) l });
}

/**
 * Decode a YUV420SP image to Luma.
 * 
 * @param yuv420sp
 *            Byte array representing a YUV420SP image.
 * @param width
 *            Width of the image.
 * @param height
 *            Height of the image.
 * @return Integer array representing the Luma image.
 * @throws NullPointerException
 *             if yuv420sp byte array is NULL.
 */
public static int[] decodeYUV420SPtoLuma(byte[] yuv420sp, int width, int height) {
    if (yuv420sp == null) throw new NullPointerException();

    final int frameSize = width * height;
    int[] hsl = new int[frameSize];

    for (int j = 0, yp = 0; j < height; j++) {
        for (int i = 0; i < width; i++, yp++) {
            int y = (0xff & (yuv420sp[yp])) - 16;
            if (y < 0) y = 0;
            hsl[yp] = y;
        }
    }
    return hsl;
}

/**
 * Decode a YUV420SP image to RGB.
 * 
 * @param yuv420sp
 *            Byte array representing a YUV420SP image.
 * @param width
 *            Width of the image.
 * @param height
 *            Height of the image.
 * @return Integer array representing the RGB image.
 * @throws NullPointerException
 *             if yuv420sp byte array is NULL.
 */
public static int[] decodeYUV420SPtoRGB(byte[] yuv420sp, int width, int height) {
    if (yuv420sp == null) throw new NullPointerException();

    final int frameSize = width * height;
    int[] rgb = new int[frameSize];

    for (int j = 0, yp = 0; j < height; j++) {
        int uvp = frameSize + (j >> 1) * width, u = 0, v = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < width; i++, yp++) {
            int y = (0xff & (yuv420sp[yp])) - 16;
            if (y < 0) y = 0;
            if ((i & 1) == 0) {
                v = (0xff & yuv420sp[uvp++]) - 128;
                u = (0xff & yuv420sp[uvp++]) - 128;
            }
            int y1192 = 1192 * y;
            int r = (y1192 + 1634 * v);
            int g = (y1192 - 833 * v - 400 * u);
            int b = (y1192 + 2066 * u);

            if (r < 0) r = 0;
            else if (r > 262143) r = 262143;
            if (g < 0) g = 0;
            else if (g > 262143) g = 262143;
            if (b < 0) b = 0;
            else if (b > 262143) b = 262143;

            rgb[yp] = 0xff000000 | ((r << 6) & 0xff0000) | ((g >> 2) & 0xff00) | ((b >> 10) & 0xff);
        }
    }
    return rgb;
}

/**
 * Convert an RGB image into a Bitmap.
 * 
 * @param rgb
 *            Integer array representing an RGB image.
 * @param width
 *            Width of the image.
 * @param height
 *            Height of the image.
 * @return Bitmap of the RGB image.
 * @throws NullPointerException
 *             if RGB integer array is NULL.
 */
public static Bitmap rgbToBitmap(int[] rgb, int width, int height) {
    if (rgb == null) throw new NullPointerException();

    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
    bitmap.setPixels(rgb, 0, width, 0, 0, width, height);
    return bitmap;
}

/**
 * Convert an Luma image into Greyscale.
 * 
 * @param lum
 *            Integer array representing an Luma image.
 * @param width
 *            Width of the image.
 * @param height
 *            Height of the image.
 * @return Bitmap of the Luma image.
 * @throws NullPointerException
 *             if RGB integer array is NULL.
 */
public static Bitmap lumaToGreyscale(int[] lum, int width, int height) {
    if (lum == null) throw new NullPointerException();

    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
    for (int y = 0, xy = 0; y < bitmap.getHeight(); y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < bitmap.getWidth(); x++, xy++) {
            int luma = lum[xy];
            bitmap.setPixel(x, y, Color.argb(1, luma, luma, luma));
        }
    }
    return bitmap;
}

/**
 * Rotate the given Bitmap by the given degrees.
 * 
 * @param bmp
 *            Bitmap to rotate.
 * @param degrees
 *            Degrees to rotate.
 * @return Bitmap which was rotated.
 */
public static Bitmap rotate(Bitmap bmp, int degrees) {
    if (bmp == null) throw new NullPointerException();

    // getting scales of the image
    int width = bmp.getWidth();
    int height = bmp.getHeight();

    // Creating a Matrix and rotating it to 90 degrees
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    matrix.postRotate(degrees);

    // Getting the rotated Bitmap
    Bitmap rotatedBmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp, 0, 0, width, height, matrix, true);
    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    rotatedBmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
    return rotatedBmp;
}

/**
 * Rotate the given image in byte array format by the given degrees.
 * 
 * @param data
 *            Bitmap to rotate in byte array form.
 * @param degrees
 *            Degrees to rotate.
 * @return Byte array format of an image which was rotated.
 */
public static byte[] rotate(byte[] data, int degrees) {
    if (data == null) throw new NullPointerException();

    // Convert the byte data into a Bitmap
    Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);

    // Getting the rotated Bitmap
    Bitmap rotatedBmp = rotate(bmp, degrees);

    // Get the byte array from the Bitmap
    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    rotatedBmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
    return stream.toByteArray();
}
}
```

Comment: removing `first[ij] = Color.RED` should not affect the remainder of the provided code.

Comment: @Piglet It fixed the issue. Thanks a lot. Please post this as an answer so that I could accept it.

Comment: in your question you said that this stopped the code from working...

Comment: @Piglet But now it worked. I don't understand how. Earlier it was not taking pictures when that instruction is removed

Comment: @Piglet Could you please take a look at this another question of mine?